# Renting a van out of Geneva airport

Tags: budget, car-rentals, switzerland

I need to rent a 7-passenger van starting Aug 3rd at the Geneva airport (either Swiss or French side).

The usual international car rental companies either don't have availability or have ridiculously high prices, disproportionate compared to mid-size or even large sedans. Renting two sedans is not an option unfortunately.

Does somebody have a recommendation for a locally operated car rental company or some other idea on how to find a van for rent?

Comment: Not a recommendation as I just found it with a web search but could this be a solution: http://aalt.ch?

Comment: I rented a van in Sarajevo a few summers ago and also found the prices to be exorbitant with the usual international rental chains.  I found a local company with a reasonable rate, so you are probably right to look for the same in Geneva.  The company was in town, not at the airport.

Comment: Unfortunately everything is expensive in Switzerland.

Answer (score 2):

As pointed in a comment Switzerland is an extremely expensive country. Unless you actually work there, anything you want to buy or rent will come at an outrageous price.

So have a look at companies located in France. Mind that you may have to consider companies a bit further away from the border, anything close to the Swiss border is usually more expensive. There are trains and shuttle buses (cheapest option I believe) leaving from Geneva airport to different cities an hour or so away. Check if any rental company propose a pick up point in one of those cities.

Mind that if you plan to cross borders with this vehicle you might need to get this approved by the car rental company (insurance reasons).

Good luck :)